# Vector.Dot not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, ryujit, system.numerics

I'm trying to use `System.Numeric.Vectors` nuget package (version 4.4.0), but following code does not work as expected:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cnt = Vector<int>.Count;

    var arr = new int[] { 42, 42, 42, 42 };
    var arr2 = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    var vec = new Vector<int>(arr, 0);
    var vec2 = new Vector<int>(arr2, 0);

    var result = Vector.Dot(vec, vec2);

    if (result != 168)
        throw new Exception($"Expected 168 actual {result} (cnt: {cnt}, acc:{Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated})");
}
```

Code throws exception on x64 Release .NET 4.7 build with message: `Expected 168 actual -458674576 (cnt: 4, acc:True)`.

All other builds where Vector is not hardware accelerated give correct results.

Is this bug in RyuJIT or am I doing something wrong?

---

**EDIT**

After replacing `int` with `float`, code is giving correct result. Is this code not working with `int` expected result?

Comment: The value of `cnt` is critical.  It is clear that you are running this code on a machine with an old processor, one that does not support AVX2 yet.  As-is, the program will bomb on any newer processor, Haswell and up, because the vectors are not long enough.  Like it did on my 2013 vintage laptop.  They require 8 elements.  That makes you exercise code that is not well tested, the Microsofties have nice hardware.  I had to make the vectors bigger by adding four zeros and then it worked fine.  You can file a bug, but my generic advice is to not do this when cnt is not 8.